# How to bound the integrand to show that $|f_u(x,u,\nabla u)|\le 1+ |u|^{p-1}+|\nabla u|^{p-1},$ implies the E-L term $f_u(x,u,\nabla u) \in L^{p'}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

From the book "introduction to the calculus of variations", DACOROGNA
I  am having trouble giustifying how the last inequality below comes out. p and p' are conjugate exponents

Given the growth condition  $|f_u(x,u,\nabla u)|\le 1+ |u|^{p-1}+|\nabla u|^{p-1},$

$$\int_\Omega|f_u(x,u,\nabla u)|^{p'}dx \le \beta^{p'}\int_\Omega(1+ |u|^{p-1}+|\nabla u|^{p-1})^{\frac{p}{p-1}}dx$$$$ \le \beta_1 (1+\|u\|^p_{W^{1,p}})< \infty$$  for some $\beta_1 >0$

I think there are using convexity of the function $x^{p'}, p'>1$
but I don't really get to anything. I would need a convex combination for that, and only two terms
Can someone give details on how is done?

Answer (score 1):

If $a,b\geq0$, then we would have $(a+b)^{p}\leq (2 \max(a,b))^{p} \leq 2^p(a^{p}+b^{p})$.

Comment: Can you explain what to do in the case  1+a+b  ? as in the problem

Comment: Besides I am not sure why the max^p <= a^p + b^p

Comment: Did you try to show that? @some_math_guy it's not really difficult....

Comment: @ArcticChar You are right, is just "suppose the max is a" and then "suppose that the max is b". I still not seeing how to manage the 1+a+b base though

Comment: @some_math_guy Because $(a+b+c)^{p}=(a+(b+c))^{p}$, or just replace $2$ and $\max(a,b)$ by $3$ and $\max(1,a,b)$.